# Almost surely, for all $s \ge 0$, there exist $t$, $u \ge s$ with $B_t < 0 < B_u$?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, brownian-motion

Let $(B_t)_{t \ge 0}$ be a Brownian motion starting from $0$. Then, do we have that, almost surely, for all $s \ge 0$, there exist $t$, $u \ge s$ with $B_t < 0 < B_u$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_process#Some_properties_of_sample_paths

Yes, because of the first property.

Comment: @Martingalo Yes, that and time inversion.